# esp32 cam Failed to set frame size

Tags: arduino, webserver, size, esp32

I have been researching for the solution of this problem for 4 days, but I could not solve the problem but ı didn't find any soution. I wanted to write here before returning the product. There is no problem while uploading the code. I am uploading the codes with arduino and the camera model on the module is af2569[image]

Comment: What is the voltage and current of the battery you are using? Or, are you directly using FTDI serial uploader cable for providing power? If you are using a battery, please say what pin of the esp32 cam you are connecting with the + of the battery. And if you are using an FTDI cable for providing powers, also say what pin of the esp32 cam you are connecting with the VCC of the FTDI cable.

Comment: I don't know what your power pinouts are. But this is what works for me: (esp32cam 5V to battery/FTDI + point). "DONT" connect the VCC of esp32cam with the + of battery. You should use the 5V pin of the esp32cam instead of VCC for providing + power to the board. The problems which occur with this board are usually related to insufficient voltage and current(Amps).

Comment: This is how the power circuit should look like: [https://i.imgur.com/QXikRKI.png](https://i.imgur.com/QXikRKI.png)

Comment: @ProgrammerHobbyist At first I energized through the arduino, then I thought I should energize it with another 5v, but it gave the same error again (I combined the gnds)

Comment: What was the "another" 5V you used to energize your esp32 cam? And did you connect the power supply's (+) point to esp32 cam's 5V pin or VCC pin? You should connect to the 5V pin as mentioned before. And please include the code with your post.

Comment: @ProgrammerHobbyist yes ı connect the power supply's + point to esp32 cam's 5v pin my code is webserver in example the power supply is coming from 12v adapter.

Comment: Are you serious that you are supplying 12 volts to the esp32 cam board?

Comment: Are you serious that you are supplying 12 volts to the esp32 cam board? And you can try out one more thing. While most people's esp32 cam board has an OV2460 module, yours is AF2569. And you are not the only one to face this problem. Whoever has faced this problem has the same camera model as yours. So you should definitely try changing  `#define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER` to something else. Make sure you comment this one in your code after uncommenting something else.

Comment: sorry for my bad english, yes it is true but there is a converter between 12v and esp32 to convert 5v. and ı tried #define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER   and all of them. I contacted the place where I bought it and watched the sample videos and checked the pin locations, I think I should return the product and buy from somewhere else.

Comment: If you buy one more from somewhere else, make sure it has the OV2460 module rather than AF2569 or something else. The problem you faced mostly happens with AF2569. I have one esp32 cam with OV2460 and have never faced this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The board needs 5V current. I had the same error when trying with 3.3V. Uploading worked but when running I got the same error. I switched the USB programmer to 5V, then it all worked fine.